# Specify different styles for two different tr and td elements

Tags: html, css

I have two different tables on separate pages, and I need to specify a certain style to each one. This is my code (It works with separate stylesheets, but I need it to work on one):

Here is a snippet of my tables and the CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
}


/* Table 1 css */

.table1,
th,
td {
  color: #030099;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 110%;
}


/* Table 2 css */

.pcsetup,
th,
td {
  color: #030099;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.tc1 {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h4>table 1</h4>
<table  cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="table1">
  <caption class="tc1"><strong>My PC Setup</strong></caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>CPU:</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>RAM:</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h4>table 2</h4>
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="pcsetup">
  <caption class="tc1"><b>PC Setup</b></caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><strong>CPU</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><strong>RAM</strong></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I differentiate between the two?

Comment: Full disclosure, I haven't read your code as I don't recognize or trust that domain. That said, if you want to apply different styles to different similar elements, you can use more specific selectors like `class="foo"` and a `.foo { ... }` rule, or `id="foo"` and a `#foo {. . .}` rule

Comment: My tables have already been assigned classes, but not the th and td and I don;t want to link a class to all of them individually. This is my CSS: .table1, th, td {
 color:#030099;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
 font-size:110%;

Comment: Please post your code in the question body if you feel it's relevant. Take a look at [mcve] for tips on how best to do this.

Comment: `.pcsetup th, .pcsetup td {...}`